# If the series $\sum n a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum a_n$ converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If the series $\sum n a_n$ is convergent, then what can we say about $\sum a_n$ ? I think $\sum a_n$ must converge to zero. Here is my proof.

$\sum n a_n$ is convergent

$\Rightarrow$ for $\epsilon \gt 0$ $ \exists$ $ N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$l-\epsilon \lt n a_n \lt l+\epsilon$ for all $n \geq N $

$\Rightarrow \frac{l-\epsilon}{n} \lt a_n\lt\frac{l+\epsilon}{n} $ for all $n \geq N$

Now, $\epsilon$ and $l$ are fixed. So, by sandwich theorem for sequences, we can conclude that $a_n$ converges to zero.

Am I correct? Thanks.

There may be similar question like this.   But I am asking whether this proof is correct or not. So, this is not duplicate.

Comment: What is $l$? And you don't want to show that $a_n$ converges to $0$ , you want to show that $\sum a_n$ does.

Comment: Why do you think it should converge to zero? We can find easily some counterexample.

Comment: @Thomas Oh so I proved by mistake that sequence $a_n$ converges to zero. But which is obvious for convergent sequence. I realized my mistake. Tnx

Comment: By $l$ I meant limit of $\sum n a_n$. But my first implication is also wrong. I can write this way only if we are talking about sequence $n a_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let consider

$$a_n=\frac1{n^3}\implies \sum n a_n
=\sum \frac1{n^2}
$$

which converges but

$$\sum \frac1{n^3}$$

doesn't converges to zero.

Comment: Tnx. By mistake I proved sequence $a_n $ converges to zero. Only we can say that $a_n $ is convergent.

Comment: @ramanujan Yes of course $na_n \to 0 \implies a_n \to 0$